# Can I save multiple JavaScript Object methods as a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, methods

I am writing an extension for a text-editor (Brackets) that can generate HTML and append libraries automatically in the HTML.

I have an Object called 'choice'.

This modal requests the users input: 
[image: Imgur]

choice grabs the user's input by defining methods on choice

**partial JS here:**

```
var choice = new Object();

    choice.language = function () {
        //Buid HTML top 'head'
        var htmlTop = "<!DOCTYPE html>" + "<html>" + "<head lang='";
        //Grab Selected Language Type
        var languageChoice = document.getElementById("languages").value;
        //Determine what Selected Language type is and complete HTML 'head'
        if (languageChoice === "english") {
          languageChoice = "en";
          return htmlTop + languageChoice + "'>";
        } else if (languageChoice === "german") {
          languageChoice = "de";
          return htmlTop + languageChoice + "'>";
        } else if (languageChoice === "spanish") {
          languageChoice = "es";
          return htmlTop + languageChoice + "'>";
        } else if (languageChoice === "french") {
          languageChoice = "fr";
          return htmlTop + languageChoice + "'>";
        } else if (languageChoice === "italian") {
          languageChoice = "it";
          return htmlTop + languageChoice + "'>";
        } else if (languageChoice === "chinese") {
          languageChoice = "zh-cn";
          return htmlTop + languageChoice + "'>";
        }
      }; //end choice.language

    choice.charset = function () {
        //Build meta and the rest of the 'head tag'
        var htmlCharset_Beginning = "<meta charset='";
        var htmlCharset_End = "'>" + "<title> -Insert Title- </title>" + "<!-- Insert CSS links below -->" + "</head>" + "<body>";
        var charsetChoice = document.getElementById("charset").value;
        if (charsetChoice === "utf8") {
          charsetChoice = "UTF-8";
          return htmlCharset_Beginning + charsetChoice + htmlCharset_End;
        } else {
          charsetChoice = "UTF-16";
          return htmlCharset_Beginning + charsetChoice + htmlCharset_End;
        }
      }; // end choice.charset

    choice.doctype = function () {
      var doctypeChoice = document.getElementById("doctype").value;
      return doctypeChoice;
    }; // end doctype

    choice.libraries = function () {
      var checkedBoxes = getCheckedBoxes("lib_checkboxes");
      checkedBoxes.forEach(function(item){
      var scripts =+ $(item).data('script');

   });//End forEach
      var bottomHTML = scripts + "</body>" + "</html>";
      return bottomHTML;
    }; //End choice.libraries


    var chosenTemplate = function(){
    var template = choice.language() + choice.charset() + choice.libraries();

      // insert html into file, this will overwrite whatever content happens to be there already
      EditorManager.getCurrentFullEditor()._codeMirror.setValue(template);

      // automatically close the modal window
      $('#templates_modalBtn').click();
    };

    //Get checkedBoxes function
    // Pass the checkbox name to the function
    function getCheckedBoxes(chkboxName) {
      var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(chkboxName);
      var checkboxesChecked = [];
      // loop over them all
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        // And stick the checked ones onto an array...
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
          checkboxesChecked.push(checkboxes[i]);
        }
      }
      // Return the array if it is non-empty, or null
      return checkboxesChecked.length > 0 ? checkboxesChecked : null;
    }


  } // End action();

  //JEFF STOP CODING HERE

  // Register the commands and insert in the File menu
  CommandManager.register(Strings.MENU_COMMAND, 'templates', action);
  var menu = Menus.getMenu(Menus.AppMenuBar.EDIT_MENU);
  menu.addMenuDivider();
  menu.addMenuItem('templates');

}); //end define;
```

---

**QUESTION:**

Can I save multiple methods (each method returns a string) as a variable?

Example here:

```
  var chosenTemplate = function(){
    var template = choice.language() + choice.charset() + choice.libraries();

      // insert html into file, this will overwrite whatever content happens to be there already
      EditorManager.getCurrentFullEditor()._codeMirror.setValue(template);

      // automatically close the modal window
      $('#templates_modalBtn').click();
    };
```

---

My code is loading with no errors, but its not executing at all so I am trying to debug and figure out what is going wrong...

Comment: `choice.libraries()` isn't actually returning anything, by the way.

Comment: How can I make it return something?  In my code I have it as 'return bottomHTML'

Comment: I fixed it I think, you can look at it now again please @Purag

Comment: do you have a plunkr or a working demo? it's hard to see what's going on, especially since `EditorManager` is not included in the code you provided

Comment: If there a way to check the value of the `template` variable? Check if it has the right string content in it after building it.

Comment: @Daniel_L I don't have a working copy yet, its for a Brackets Extension so it cannot execute outside of brackets (to my knowledge).  [Here](http://brackets.io/docs/current/modules/editor/EditorManager.html) is the API documentation for EditorManager

Comment: @Purag I assume I can just console.log(template).  I am in the process of debugging.  Thanks I will do that!

Comment: Also, in `choice.libraries()`, you need to declare `scripts` outside of the `forEach`. You create the variable inside the loop so you lose whatever you put in it every time. ;) Also, use `+=`, not `=+`.

Comment: @Purag thank you, I literally just caught that error too.  Thanks!

Comment: You should really learn to work with objects. A lot of your code can be made a lot cleaner and less prone to errors. I would submit it for http://codereview.stackexchange.com if I were you. Fixing your frail logic would probably fix whatever doubts you're having as well.

Comment: Just a comment to improve your code. In your language `<select>`, your options could be like this: `<option value="en">English</option>`. Then, your `choice.language()` function is reduced to just concatenate the value with your html.

Comment: @Jan Your absolutely right.  I am writing these extensions to try and get some hands-on experience with Objects and OOP.  I referred to OOP documentation and examples a lot.  I know I have a lot to learn, but thats half the fun! 

I will submit it to the code review area.  Thanks!

Comment: @JoaquínO Ah, I see what your saying.  Your right, that would probably be faster and more direct compared to what I am currently doing.  I will add that to my refactor list. Thanks!

Comment: Just to show you an example of what you could do instead, here's the top part of your code pretty much reduced by half: http://jsbin.com/rutawewiza/edit?js Just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Before you realize the function 'chosenTemplate', you should check whether the document stream of the page has already downloaded. If it not, you may not be able to get the value of the widget (empty).

Comment: How would one do that? Theoretically?  Thanks for the input!

Comment: Would wrapping my code in a $(document).ready(function(){}); do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, wrapping  code in a $(document).ready(function(){}) may help